# Difficulties formatting JSON for Azure function input

Tags: json, powershell, api, azure-functions, postman

I need so send below's JSON to an Azure function in order to process a XMLA query.
How do I fix below's JSON in order to send the JSON to the Azure function?

```
{"WorkspaceId": "workspaceid", "DatasetId": "datasetid", 
  
"XMLA_String": "{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "datamodel",
        "table": "datatable"
      }
    ]
  }
}"}
```

Comment: can you show the code that produced your json. It is not valid and I am wonderig how you would able to produce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
{
  "WorkspaceId": "workspaceid",
  "DatasetId": "datasetid",
  "XMLA_String": "{\"refresh\": {\"type\": \"full\", \"objects\": [{ \"database\": \"datamodel\", \"table\": \"datatable\" }]}}"
}
```

Comment: thank you, it does the trick